# Specifying a group variable on the ansible command line

Tags: ansible

Ansible allows the creation of variables that pertain only to a group in the inventory file as follows:

```
[DC1:vars]
node_availability=available

[DC2:vars]
node_availability=unavailable
```

I would like to do this on the command line instead, using the `--extra-vars` parameter.  Any idea how this may be accomplished?  I've tried various permutations of `group.DC1.node_availability=available` and the like to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra vars are different thing, so you can't set group vars via command line directly.
But you can template group vars, like this:

```
[DC1:vars]
node_availability={{dc1var | default('unavailable')}}
```

And passing `-e dc1var=test` will thus set your group variable.